# Email, gender, age not returned with Omniauth and facebook API 2.4

Tags: facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I could **NOT** get back the email information anymore with `Omniauth`.

I think the problem is duing to the API 2.4,

But I don't get how could I the the expected information

## Devise config

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], {
  :scope => 'email',
  :info_fields => 'id,email,gender,link,locale,name,timezone,updated_time,verified',
  strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook,
  :provider_ignores_state => true}
```

## Returned information not including email information

```
:1> env['omniauth.auth']
{
       "provider" => "facebook",
            "uid" => "xxxx",
           "info" => {
         "name" => "Eric Hsu",
        "image" => "http://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/picture?type=square"
    },
    "credentials" => {
             "token" => "CAAh",
        "expires_at" => 1443066205,
           "expires" => true
    },
          "extra" => {
        "raw_info" => {
            "name" => "Eric Hsu",
              "id" => "xxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The fields have to be requested via the `fields` parameter in the actual Graph API request that is made. If that part is not exposed to you by omniauth, then you will have to wait for them to update their code.

Comment: I add info_fields like you did and it worked thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is that the dependency between FB API and omniauth-facebook version.
current i installed the gem `omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)`